# Concatenate video files to get a single video in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, merge, mp4

I would like to know which is the best or the most efficient library to concatenate video files. I'm working in a Rails project and I need to merge different video files to get one video in mp4. I've been searching in Internet but I don't see a clear and easy solution. So if you could give a good advice I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I also found this link detailing how to use Mencoder or MP4Box.
http://superuser.com/questions/227315/concatenate-two-mp4-videos-into-one-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best choice might be [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/)

You will be able to manipulate video input and audio as well as many other things, and for the concatenation you could use the following

`system "ffmpeg -i concat: \"#{video source(path)} | #{other video source (path)}\" -c copy #{name_of_output_file}"`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
# Usage: 
#   output_path = ConcatVideoFilesService.new.perform(video_paths)
class ConcatVideoFilesService
  def perform(video_paths, output_path = nil)
    output_path ||= Dir::Tmpname.create(["concat_video_files_out_put", ".webm"]) {}
    video_paths_path = Dir::Tmpname.create(["concat_video_files_list", ".txt"]) {}

    File.open(video_paths_path, "w") do |f|
      video_paths.each do |video_path|
        f.write("file '#{video_path}' \n")
      end
    end

    begin
      system "ffmpeg -avoid_negative_ts 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i #{video_paths_path} -c copy #{output_path}"
      return output_path
    ensure
      File.delete(video_paths_path) if File.exists?(video_paths_path)
    end
  end
end
```